# Django Rest CORS Permissions Default

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-cors-headers

I am in the process of building a React App to talk to Django as the backend via the Django Rest Framework. I have installed the relevant packages and am trying to configure my default behavour when accessing the views to block access and have the following in my settings.py file

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PREMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ],
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
    ]
}
```

My view access the data is:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import JsonResponse
from .models import Articles
from .serializers import ArticleSerializer

# Create your views here.


def articles_list(request):
    articles = Articles.objects.all()
    serializer = ArticleSerializer(articles, many=True)
    return JsonResponse(serializer.data, safe=False)


def get_article(request, articlename):
    article = Articles.objects.get(name=articlename)
    serializer = ArticleSerializer(article, many=False)
    return JsonResponse(serializer.data, safe=False)
```

Am I missing something completely simple as I can still access this when when not currently authenticated to the Django backend.

Thanks

Comment: are you facing CORS issue or any authentication issue?

Comment: From what I can see is an authentication issue, in the sense that from my understanding with the default set to: 'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated' I expect it to not allow me to access the API. However it seems to still allow access.

Comment: You need to use GenericView or API view and add permission attribute inside your class to work authentication .